# change overlay opacity from scrolling position

Tags: javascript, css, parallax

i have a site with some sections, there is one “image section”, this section is about 3000px height and the background-image is fixed so I get a nice effect - and after a while scrolling into this image section I want to show an information-text. This part already works fine.

What I want:
After the text is shown and after a small time (with time I mean a few scroll steps) to read the text I want to decrease the opacity to 0 (with the scroll position) at about 100px before the section ends.

```
<section class="box red">

</section>
<section class="box blue">

</section>
<section class="image-section">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="overlay-text">
      lorem ipsum
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="box red mysection">

</section>
<section class="box blue">

</section>
```

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e53f9m55/3/
(in the js section the top is the bullseye plugin, just ignore it)

Answer (score 0):

You are already changing the opacity of the overlay on relation with the distance from top, so you could do a similar thing with the distance from bottom. Something like this:

```
var distanceFromBottom = $(document).height() - $(window).height() - $(window).scrollTop();
opacity_text = distanceFromBottom / $(document).height();
$(".overlay-text").css({"opacity" : opacity_text});
```

Comment: nice answer, thanks but how can i make distanceFromBottom NOT depend on the document height? is this possible?

Comment: Of course, you can do it with any scrollable container, take a look to this fiddle where you can see it: https://jsfiddle.net/jolmos/6Ly0eLn9/

Comment: ok i didn't worked with scrollable containers... i testet it, but i have to scroll exactly in the container and when i scroll like usally the event dont fire.. and when i want to hide the scrollbar with overflow hidden its not working anymore

Comment: It's just an idea, you have to play a bit with it, check the update of your fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/e53f9m55/5/